# Full render showing nothing

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

My object is not showing in Full Render mode.
It is modeled and textured in another software, so in Blender there are no actual textures nor materials connected to the object, but they are there in the 3D view when the Method to display/shade objects in 3D view is set on Texture.
Does anybody know what might be the problem?

[image: screen shot of blender showing the blank render]

Comment: Does this work? :)
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?226228-Objects-not-rendering-Blank-render If not, then it will probably be of great help to include the .blend file for someone knowledgable to take a look at.